# Using counter in map, lambda in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I need to create this list ["1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345", ..., "123456789"] without using loops. How can I do it by using map, lambda functions?

I can do it like in the code writthen below, but that's not what I need:

```
lst = []
        num = ""
        for i in range(1,10):
            num += str(i)
            lst.append(num)
        print(lst)
```

I also tried this:
lst = list(map(lambda x: str(x), range(1,10))) ,
but I got ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] instead of ["1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345", ..., "123456789"].

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Why? Is there any reason because map and lambda functions would work better here? Did you tried something with map and lambdas?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I'm just learning map and lambda. I tried this: 
lst = list(map(lambda x: str(x), range(1,10)))
I got ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] instead of ["1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345", ..., "123456789"]

Comment: @New2905 [edit] your question to add what you tried. It may help to revert some of the downvotes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt of `list(map(lambda x: str(x), range(1,10)))` is a good start, but in order to produce a string of incremental numbers joined together you can map another `range` generator to `str` and concatenate them with `''.join`:

```
list(map(lambda n: ''.join(map(str, range(1, n + 1))), range(1, 10)))
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/zbOTvh

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
[e[:n] for n, e in enumerate(["123456789"]*10, 1)]
```

but not map or lambda.